# Trouble with identical and all.equal when comparing two floating point elements in two vectors

Tags: r, floating-point, comparison, floating-accuracy

This is a follow up to a question I posted [**yesterday**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465505/relational-operator-is-not-producing-the-expected-answer-in-r).  I can't seem to get things right about floating point comparison in R. Yesterday I was using `>=` to compare two floating point values but that dint seem to get the right results.

Today, I [**tried**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) to run `all.equal`, element-wise, on two vectors, which yielded a `mean difference`, which does not work for this application. I need the comparison function *to return a vector*. Then, I found `identical` and combined it with `mapply`. This became more accurate, but not 100% accurate.  What am I doing wrong? Since this is financial data, should I be using a [**decimal data type**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874867/floating-point-issue-in-r)?  If so, how?

*From yesterday's post (with updated code, reflecting current frustration):*

**The goal is to:** read the data into a `data.frame`, take an average of yesterday's `High`, `Low`, and `Close` prices; and, compare today's Open price with yesterday's average.

After running the scripts on large data, I found that my results in `R` **didn't match** a similar analysis run in `Excel`. I've scaled down the problem to it's essential parts. My test file, `test.csv`, looks like this, including a new line at the end of the last row:

```
<TICKER>,<DATE>,<TIME>,<OPEN>,<LOW>,<HIGH>,<CLOSE>
EURUSD,20020311,0:00:00,0.8733,0.873,0.877,0.8749
EURUSD,20020312,0:00:00,0.8749,0.8704,0.876,0.8754
EURUSD,20020313,0:00:00,0.8753,0.8725,0.878,0.8754
EURUSD,20020314,0:00:00,0.8753,0.8752,0.8841,0.8823
EURUSD,20020315,0:00:00,0.8823,0.8808,0.8868,0.8823
EURUSD,20020318,0:00:00,0.8809,0.878,0.8828,0.8821
EURUSD,20020319,0:00:00,0.8821,0.8796,0.884,0.8816
EURUSD,20020320,0:00:00,0.8815,0.8786,0.8857,0.8855
EURUSD,20020321,0:00:00,0.8854,0.8806,0.8857,0.8823
```

My Code:

```
# Read in test file
raw <- read.csv('test.csv', header=TRUE, sep=",")

# Convert date and dump dat into data frame
stripday <- strptime(raw$X.DATE, format="%Y%m%d")
data <- data.frame(stripday, raw)

# Drop unused data columns and name used columns
drops <- c("X.DATE.", "X.TIME.", "X.TICKER.")
data <- data[, !(names(data) %in% drops)]
colnames(data) <- c("Date", "Open", "Low", "High", "Close")

# Convert values from facotrs to numeric
data[,2] <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,2]))
data[,3] <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,3]))
data[,4] <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,4]))
data[,5] <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,5]))

# Take average of High, Low, and Close 
data[['Avg']] <- NA
data[['Avg']][2:9] <- (
    data[['High']][1:8] + 
    data[['Low']][1:8] + 
    data[['Close']][1:8]) / 3

# Is Open greater than or equal to Average
data[['OpenGreaterThanOrEqualAvg']] <- NA
data[['OpenGreaterThanOrEqualAvg']][2:9] <- 1 * (mapply(identical,data[['Open']][2:9], data[['Avg']][2:9]) | data[['Open']][2:9] > data[['Avg']][2:9])

# Write data to .csv
write.table(data, 'output.csv', quote=FALSE, sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
```

Note that there should be a 1, not 0, for 3/14/2002.

Comment: This has the same answer as your prior question. It's a result of floating point arithmetic. And if you weren't confused enough, there's a 1 on 2012-03-14 when I run your code.

Comment: Just to clarify: `all.equal` will result in TRUE if the comparison succeeds. Else, it'll return *not* FALSE, but the *mean absolute difference* **or** *mean relative difference*. [**See here for more info on `all.equal`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334701/how-does-the-tolerance-parameter-of-all-equal-work/15334737#15334737)

Comment: Arun, you are correct; however, I am needed a function that returned a vector, not a TRUE.

Comment: Joshua Ulrich, I think I may cry.  Is it my environment?  I'm working in RStudio 0.97.168 on Windows 7.

Comment: @Brian, I cut down the post a bit, it was too long and may sway some readers off from finishing to read...

Comment: @Brian, it gives me a `0` for `3/14/2002`. I'm trying to go through your code...

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, I tried it without `as.numeric(as.character(.))`.

Comment: @Brian, what's the answer you expect for that entire column?

Comment: @Arun: `with(data, identical(Open[4],Avg[4])` is `TRUE` if you calculate `Avg` as `data$Avg <- c(NA, rowMeans(data[1:8,3:5]))`.  But that's just lucky. It's generally futile to try and figure out how to get *exactly* the same floating point numbers.

Comment: aha.. that's trickier than I imagined.

Comment: @Arun: it's not tricky... it was sheer luck. I simply didn't like how the OP calculated the average, so I did it "my" way and the numbers happened to be identical.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses.  I appreciate it.  I still do not see how the article posted brings me closer to a solution.  As I mentioned in my original question, all.equal does not return a vector , but a single TRUE or mean relative difference.