# Symmetric matrix checking: how does tolerance work?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix (mat1). When testing symmetry:

> isSymmetric(mat1,tol = 0)
>
> > FALSE

Which means that with zero-tolerance, the matrix not symmetric. However testing with slightly larger tolerance, the matrix is deemed symmetric:

> isSymmetric(mat1,tol = 10 * .Machine$double.eps)
>
> > TRUE

However, the maximum difference between symmetric entries is greater than this tolerance value:

> max(abs(mat1-t(mat1))) > (10 * .Machine$double.eps)
>
> > TRUE

Why, when there is a symmetric difference greater than the tolerance value, is the matrix classified as symmetric?

For a worked example using the ?glm example:

```
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts)
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())
mat1 <- solve(vcov(glm.D93))

isSymmetric(mat1,tol=0) # FALSE
isSymmetric(mat1,tol=10 * .Machine$double.eps) # TRUE
max(abs(mat1-t(mat1))) > (10 * .Machine$double.eps) # TRUE
```

I likely do not understand how tolerance works; my thinking was that values larger than the tolerance threshold would make the matrix symmetry test fail, which apparently is not the case.

Comment: have you looked at `isSymmetric.matrix` for details?  that will lead you to  `all.equal(mat1,t(mat1))` or `all.equal(c(abs(mat1-t(mat1))),rep(0,length(mat1)))` (which are both TRUE).  Then see `?all.equal` and `all.equal.numeric`

Comment: @BenBolker all.equal also has a default setting - .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5 - which is significantly smaller than what I am testing, so using that instead of isSymmetric, I can also get to show the matrix is not symmetric: all.equal(mat1,t(mat1),tolerance=0)

Comment: But that is not my main concern - when I deliberately set tolerance smaller than the largest value (i.e. max(abs(mat1-t(mat1)))) - all.equal(mat1,t(mat1),tolerance=10 * .Machine$double.eps) why is this TRUE? In testing all.equal with that tolerance, any value difference greater would make it false...2.13162e-14 > 2.220446e-15 (right?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the tolerance parameter of all.equal() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334701/how-does-the-tolerance-parameter-of-all-equal-work)

Comment: I flagged as a duplicate. The short story is that the relative, not absolute difference is compared to the tolerance. And it's relative to the mean absolute values in the second argument of `all.equal`.

Comment: I suppose that you could see that other answer as a duplicate but it was really addressing a different misconception about `all.equal`. The only examples used were single element vectors and the issue was whether relative or absolute difference were being chosen as the standard of comparison. There really was no discussion of that fact that mean values were being used when the vectors were multi-element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BenBolker told you to look at the help page for isSymmetric which directs you to `all.equal`. You built this matrix:

```
> mat1
            (Intercept)     outcome2     outcome3   treatment2   treatment3
(Intercept)         150 4.000000e+01 4.700000e+01 5.000000e+01 5.000000e+01
outcome2             40 4.000000e+01 2.237910e-14 1.333333e+01 1.333333e+01
outcome3             47 2.476834e-14 4.700000e+01 1.566667e+01 1.566667e+01
treatment2           50 1.333333e+01 1.566667e+01 5.000000e+01 2.710506e-14
treatment3           50 1.333333e+01 1.566667e+01 2.818926e-14 5.000000e+01
```

The test in `all.equal` is `tolerance = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5`, so none of your tests were actually the same as the one without an argument. (In the case of very small numbers the sqrt is actually quite a bit bigger.)   Notice there is an additional test regarding equality of row and column names which your example would have satisfied.

If you look at the help page you should become suspicious about your understanding of what all.equal might be doing when yious see sthat is is `testing ‘near equality’` and then refers you to the Details where it says:

```
 Numerical comparisons for scale = NULL (the default) are done by first computing the mean 
 absolute difference of the two numerical vectors.
```

In the code you can see that it is not individual differences being tested relative to the tolerance but the mean absolute differences.

Comment: Right, my tests were not the same as the default tolerance for all.equal. I am setting the tolerance value, so not testing tolerance at .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5. Using the tolerance I specified in isSymmetric (10 * .Machine$double.eps - which can also be used in all.equal), I found that the matrix is deemed symmetric even though there is a difference greater than this tolerance value - i.e. max(abs(mat1-t(mat1))) Maybe I don't understand "tolerance": to me it means it will "accept" differences as long as they are below the tolerance threshold... but there is a difference greater than this!